# Как использовать кнопки и подсказки при вводе команд, присутствующие в верифицированных ботах в библиотеке discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

При использовании бота **Juniper Bot** я заметил кнопки, которых нет у обычных ботов, но эту функцию мне хотелось бы использовать. Можете пожалуйста сказать, как использовать изображённые снизу функцию (**Juniper Bot**) и подсказки в строке ввода (**Shadbot**) в библиотеке **discord.py**
[image: Большие реакции]

[image: Подсказка в строке ввода]

Comment: А что подразумевается под "специальными функциями”? Уточните

Comment: Эти функции изображены в скриншотах
Например, в первом там вместо маленьких обычных реакций, большие, которые ставятся мгновенно, во втором, функция с подсказкой текущего аргумента в строке ввода

Answer (score 1):

Кнопки и слэш-команды в официальный discord фреймворк пока не завезли, но есть готовые модули, совместимые с оригинальным [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py)

На гитхабе есть такие решения:

[dislash](https://github.com/EQUENOS/dislash.py) поддержка слэш команд (подсказки при вводе) и кнопок

[slash-create](https://github.com/Snazzah/slash-create) поддержка слэш команд

[discord-components](https://pypi.org/project/discord-components/) поддержка кнопок

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: для спасибо кнопка есть